# Como salvar várias inputs com o mesmo "name"?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando salvar várias input que contém a mesma `"name"`, mas o problema é que ele só salva 1 único resultado pra várias.
Exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="guardar.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="teste1">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="teste2">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="teste3">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="teste4">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="teste5">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
$produtos = $_POST["produto"];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO produtos (produtos) VALUES ("$produtos"") or die("Erro  query.<br>Mensagem do servidor: ".mysql_error());
```

Mas no banco vem apenas:

> teste1

Como eu salvaria todos os valores das inputs se elas tem a mesma `name`?

***Atualização:***

O Problema foi resolvido adicionando `[]` as `name` das `input`, transformando-a em uma `array` e as tratando depois com `foreach`.

Comment: Porque você não troca o nome, neste caso específico não estou vendo nenhuma razão para usar o mesmo nome.

Comment: o problema é que estas `input` são gerados automaticamente a cada click do usuário em um valor no site.
se ele selecionar 3 produtos?
teria que ser uma `input` produtos pra cada uma, queria tentar outra forma além de gerar uma `input` com uma `name` diferente pra cada item.

Comment: Se você der o nome de `produtos[]` aos seus inputs, creio que eles serão enviados ao PHP como um array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Olá, como dito nos comentários, basta transformá-los em um array:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="guardar.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="teste1">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="teste2">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="teste3">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="teste4">
    <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="teste5">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

No PHP você coloca os inserts dentro de um loop que passa pelos campos do array:

PHP

```
foreach($_POST["produto"] as $produto) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO produtos (produtos) VALUES (".$produto.")") or die("Erro  query.<br>Mensagem do servidor: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: +1 Recomendo que seja verificado se existe a entrada `produto` e se a mesma é uma matriz antes de charmar o `foreach()` ou vamos ter alguns erros! Ex.: `isset($_POST["produto"]) && is_array($_POST["produto"])`.

Comment: Muito bom, deu certo!