# Remover DIV clonada, ao clicar em button

Tags: javascript, html, css

A algum tempo eu fiz uma pergunta sobre como fazer para clonar uma DIV de um form ao clicar em um button ( + )...

Obtive a seguinte resposta que me ajudou na época.

> [RESPOSTA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70069/clonar-input-text-e-passar-o-valor-do-input-clonado-via-post)

Agora, preciso adicionar um novo button ( - ) para que quando o usuário clique, a div clonada seja removida.

Código JS atual:

> Elaborado por: [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)

```
function mais() {
    var destino = document.getElementById("aqui");
    var novadiv = document.createElement("div");
    var conteudo = document.getElementById("servico");
    novadiv.innerHTML = conteudo.innerHTML;
    destino.appendChild(novadiv);
}
```

Preciso de ajuda para implementar uma function que faça o seguinte:

```
function menos(){
    //remove ultima div clonada...
}
```

**jsFiddle:** [jsfiddle.net/qf2Lf914/](http://jsfiddle.net/qf2Lf914/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assim?

```
function menos()
{
    var destino = document.getElementById("aqui");
    if (destino.lastChild)
    {
        destino.removeChild(destino.lastChild);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qf2Lf914/1/

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado!