# Salvar vários dados de text boxes com nomes iguais

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Em meu projeto tenho uma regra que é salvar varios campos com o mesmo nome de uma vez só.

Hoje, funciona o cadastramento, mas somente de um campo somente, e não é isso que quero.. Eu preciso que ao clicar para salvar, todos os campos sejam salvos, gerando registros na tabela diferentes.

Para ficar mais claro, tenho essa tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho 12 campos ao total, mas cada um representa um tipo de dado diferente.

O "Tipo", "Horario/Local" e "Alimentos/Quantidades" são campos onde eu tenho 6 tipos, os horarios e locais e alimentos e quantidades...

Preciso salvar tudo dessa forma, todos os dados de uma vez só... Como posso fazer isso?

Mais ou menos o estilo [dessa pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56231/como-salvar-v%C3%A1rias-inputs-com-o-mesmo-name), a diferença é que uso asp.net mvc ao invés do PHP.

## EDIT

Por falha minha eu esqueci de comentar que, essa imagem fica em um model que é um partial sendo renderizado dentro de uma view master.. O que acontece é que tenho um ViewModel e dentro dele várias classes, inclusive essa que representada na imagem.

Comment: Não entendi campos diferentes!

Comment: São os mesmos campos, só que replicados várias vezes. Na minha tabela tenho somente 3 colunas, o quero é replicar na view e salvar tudo...

Comment: mas, você precisa dizer se na View ele vai ter que criar os campos ou vai ser 12 linhas como padrão ?

Comment: As doze linhas como padrão

Comment: [Não é isto que você quer?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem)

Comment: Talvez sim, mas não consegui entender direito como funciona... @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Ao que me parece, não são necessariamente 12 campos. Pode ser mais ou menos. Se for, é o caso de BeginCollectionItem. Assim sendo, ainda gostaria de mais uma resposta?

Comment: Sim, sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez, sem problemas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar uma lista de informações você precisa enumerar os dados da View. Exemplo:

***Modelo da classe:***

```
using System;
namespace WebApplication10.Models
{
    public class Modelo
    {
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }
        public int AlimentosQuantidades { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View fixa com 12 linhas e 3 colunas**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("[{0}].Tipo", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("[{0}].DataHora", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("[{0}].AlimentosQuantidades", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <button>Enviar</button>
}
```

***O código gerado por essa View (vou colocar somente 2 linhas)***

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[0].Tipo" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[0].DataHora" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[0].AlimentosQuantidades" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[1].Tipo" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[1].DataHora" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="[1].AlimentosQuantidades" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Então, com `[0].Tipo` é a primeira caixa e `[1].Tipo` é a próxima caixa do tipo e assim por diante com todos os `input`

***Controller***

```
[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult Lista()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Lista(List<Modelo> model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Lista");
}
```

*Quando mandar o formulário na `ActionResult` com `List<Modelo>` a variavel model será carregado com todas as informações*

**EDIT**

Quando se tem um `ViewModel` e um propriedade que represente essa listagem de campos, na sua `View` coloque o nome da propriedade e o resto permanece igual.

Exemplo:

***ViewModel***

using System;

```
namespace WebApplication10.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Modelo> Modelo {get;set;}
        //... os outros itens.
    }
}
```

***View***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Modelo[{0}].Tipo", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Modelo[{0}].DataHora", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Modelo[{0}].AlimentosQuantidades", i), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <button>Enviar</button>
}
```

Ou seja, nome da propriedade `Modelo`, indexação do elemento `[0]` (`[1]`, `[2]` , etc.) e Nome do campo da `classe Modelo`, resumindo `Modelo[0].Tipo` e assim sucessivamente.

***Controller***

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Lista(ViewModelExample example)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Lista");
}
```

---

Dica, é um exagero muitas vezes o uso de `ViewModel`, quando se tem já classes que podem fazer o mesmo papel, tudo que é excessivo demais em desenvolvimento, pode causar problemas na hora da manutenção, repetição de código, etc.

Talvez essa enumeração seja melhor feita antes dessa edição colocando no seu controler assim:

***Controller***

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Lista(List<Modelo> model, ViewModelExample example)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Lista");
}
```